# Sorting cubes on a shelf by moving only 4 cubes to the end of a shelf

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have a problem with the following.

There are colorful cubes on the shelf.

Each cube can be either `C - Cyan`, `M - Magenta`, `Y - Yellow` or `K - blacK`. There is a robot which have to sort all the cubes in the given order that is: looking from the left there must be colors from C to K in order. For example CCCCMMMYKKKKK. The robot can take only four adjacent cubes and place it on the right end of the shelf. Then it shifts everything to the left to fill the gap.

I have no idea how to do this :/

Any advice will be very greatful

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea of a naive algorithm -

*(example input CYKMMKYCCYK)*

iterate through the shelf, if you find a C, move it to the end of the shelf and don't touch that 'C' again. Do that for all 'C's.

*(input after this step YKMMKYYKCCC)*

iterate through the shelf, if you find a M, move it to the end of the shelf and don't touch that 'M' again. Do that for all 'M's.

*(input after this step YKKYYKCCCMMM)*

. . .  repeat for 'Y' *(input after this step KKKCCCMMMYYY)* . . .

. . .  repeat for 'K' *(input after this step CCCMMMYYYKKK)* . . .

The idea is you partitioned the shelf into two sections, the "left" section is unsorted and the "right" section is sorted. Each time you move a letter to the end, you are moving it from the "left" unsorted section to the "right" sorted section. Once all letters have been moved, the shelf is sorted.

This can be optimized to move more than one letter at a time.

Comment: It isn't as easy as you wrote ;) Robot can take ONLY four adjacent cubes

Comment: Ah that does make it trickier. Are there any more constraints on the problem? For example, the sequence of five "KMYCK" could never be sorted by only moving four adjacent cubes.

Comment: I'm afraid there aren't any. I need to check it by myself. I only got what i wrote in my post. I have no idea where to search for similar problems.